# Difference between the "@" instance variable belonging to the class object and "@@" class variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

According to [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Instance_Variables)...

- `@one` below  *is an instance variable **belonging to the class object** (note this is not the same as a class variable and could not be referred to as `@@one`)*
- `@@value` is *a class variable* (similar to static in Java or C++).
- `@two` *is an instance variable **belonging to instances** of MyClass*.

**My questions:**

What's the difference between @one and @@value?
Also, is there a reason to use @one at all?

```
class MyClass
  @one = 1
  @@value = 1

  def initialize()
    @two = 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@one` is an instance variable of the class `MyClass` and `@@value` is the class variable `MyClass`. As `@one` is an instance variable it is only owned by the class `MyClass` (*In Ruby class is also object*), not ***shareable***, but `@@value` is a ***shared variable***.

**shared variable**

```
class A
  @@var = 12
end

class B < A
  def self.meth
    @@var
  end
end

B.meth # => 12
```

**non shared variable**

```
class A
  @var = 12
end

class B < A
  def self.meth
    @var
  end
end

B.meth # => nil
```

`@two` is an instance variable of the instances of the class `MyClass`.

Instance variables are private property of objects, thus they wouldn’t share it. In Ruby classes are also objects. `@one` you defined inside a class `MyClass`, thus it is only owned by that class defining it. On the other hand `@two` instance variable will be created when you will be creating a object of the class `MyClass`, say `ob`, using `MyClass.new`. `@two` is only owned by `ob`, none other objects have any idea about it.

Comment: How is `@one` different from `@two`? I understand @two belongs to instances of MyClass, but I don't understand how can an instance variable belong to the class object only but not to instances of a class.

Comment: @ayjay Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about it is who should hold the information or be able to do a task (because it is the same for class methods vs instance methods).

```
class Person
  @@people = []

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @@people << self
  end

  def say_hello
    puts "hello, I am #{@name}"
  end
end

# Class variables and methods are things that the collection should know/do
bob = Person.new("Bob") # like creating a person
Person.class_variable_get(:@@people) # or getting a list of all the people initialized

# It doesn't make sense to as bob for a list of people or to create a new person
# but it makes sense to ask bob for his name or say hello
bob.instance_variable_get(:@name)
bob.say_hello
```

I hope that helps.